# How do I make my site multi language?

Tags: plugins, multi-language

I started getting international visits but how do I make my site multi-language? Is there a good plugin or what do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends of the setup, but in most cases this one was the best translation plugin I've used so far:

Free Version: https://wordpress.org/plugins/translatepress-multilingual/

Premium Version: https://translatepress.com/

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I found another one, https://wordpress.org/plugins/gtranslate/
I like it better because it lets you use more than 2 languages.